# How to make a minimalistic program for visual studio c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I attempted to make a simple C++ exe using visual studio, the only thing in the source file is `int main(){}`, why were different `.dll` loaded into the program?

```
 Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. 
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. 
The thread 0x40c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. 
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. 
The thread 0x1c74 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3068 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8528] Project1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Under project settings I switched "Ignore all default libraries" to "Yes", this caused errors.

```
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
```

Why is the CRT being referenced if there is no reference to it in the source file? Also, why are there three threads in the program? **Ideally I just want to use the `msvcrt.dll`or `vcruntime140d.dll`for c and c++ respectively then add other libraries I need as I go, how do I accomplish this?** Visual studio seems to be adding a lot of different things that I am not completely sure are necessary.

Comment: *"Why is the CRT being referenced if there is no reference to it in the source file"* - What do you think calls your `main` ? The default entry point of a vc++ linked image is `_mainCRTStartup` It, after setting up the standard library, wiring streams, etc, invokes your `main`. It, or a properly prepared substitute (which is possible, but not trivial) is required. And those listed DLLs are required by the runtime, thus their load.

Comment: @WhozCraig No matter what these `.dll` are going to be required for every project then, even this empty one? Why is "Ignore All Default Libraries" even an option then under project settings? Also why are there three threads being exited?

Comment: The threads are part fo the runtime. Ignore default libs and its purpose is described [in the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nodefaultlib-ignore-libraries?view=msvc-140). Chances are, if you don't know if you need it, you probably don't. Many years ago minimal component sizing was a big thing. It was feasible to utilize ATL, for example, in a no-runtime scenario, and generate PEs that were functional but only a few KB. You lose the standard runtime and all it brings (and requires), but sometimes the benefit outweighed the cost. Not so much any longer.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for the clarifications. So if I use visual studio at a minimum I am going to be stuck with the threads and these `.dll`s? Is there anyway to tell visual studio to only use the crt  `msvcrt.dll` and perhaps cut down on the `.dll`s/threads used, or does the visual studio compiler require both C/C++ runtimes? Ideally if possible I would just want to use one or the other at a time and not mix the programming languages to cut down on the `.dll`s?/threads they create.

Comment: VisualStudio is just an ide. It is possible to configure a project to consume near-nothing (and with that, get usage access to near-nothing in return).  The minimal libs you're going to require are likely kernel32.dll and user32.dll. As soon as you bring in the VC runtime you're bring with it all the baggage it requires as well. Unless you have a damn good *researched* reason to go down any of these roads it probably isn't worth the effort. Modern Windows is pretty damn efficient, especially compared to 20+ years ago.